# how i catch and insert Meteor.Error alerts From Meteor.Methods in to a client side db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteorite

i just writing a error notification panel in meteor, here i create a client side mongodb, but i cant push Meteor.Error message in to that client side db by throwError function, currently it's shows inside an alert box

collection/signup.js

```
signupDB = new Meteor.Collection('signup');

Meteor.methods({

    signupSubmit : function(postData) {

        var signinEmailExist = signinDB.findOne({
        email : postData.email
        });

        if (postData.email && signinEmailExist)
        throw new Meteor.Error(422, "exist in signinDB");

        var signupEmailExist = signupDB.findOne({
        email : postData.email
        });

        if (postData.email && signupEmailExist)
        throw new Meteor.Error(422, "exist in signupDB");       //    

        var user = _.extend(_.pick(postData, 'email', 'password'), {
            insert_time : new Date().getTime()      });

        var userId = signupDB.insert(user);

        return userId;

    }

});
```

client/error/error.js

```
errorDB = new Meteor.Collection(null);

throwError = function(data) {
    errorDB.insert({data: "in throwError", del: "N"})
}
```

`errorDB.insert({data: "in signup", del: "N"})` code is working anywhere inside client folder

here throwError function can't called, but signupSubmit method errors shows in a alert box

is the problem of publication/subscription like thinks (not wrote for signup db) ?

how i catch and insert Meteor.Error alerts From Meteor.Methods in to a client side db ?

is there any other function like throwError to trap Meteor.Methods errors ?

Comment: Check package https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you calling the method? You need to do something like:

```
Meteor.call('signupSubmit', user, function(err) {
  errorDB.insert(err);
});
```

However, you seem to be implementing a custom, insecure authentication system. You shouldn't do this; Meteor has a great, secure built-in [Accounts](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) package. All you need to do is (on the client side):

```
errors = new Meteor.Collection;

Accounts.createUser({
  email: email,
  password: password
}, function(err) {
  errors.insert(err);
});
```

The `Accounts.createUser` method automatically returns an error if the username/email is duplicated.

Comment: how i create a temporary user list for admin approval, after admin approval create user account

Comment: If your temporary user list is going to have plaintext passwords, just don't. You should always use Meteor's built in Accounts methods when dealing with passwords. For a simple way to achieve what you want, you should add something like an 'approved' field to the user's profile when you create a user, initially set to `false`. An admin-only template would contain a list of users with a button for each user which sets the user's `profile.approved` to `true`. Then, whenever the user tries to do anything, you check whether or not they are approved.

Comment: @Cuberto, good advice.  I'd also add that `profile` fields are auto-published by the accounts package and by convention are user-editable.  So the `approved` field should live off the root `user` object itself rather than `user.profile`.